# For $\lambda(A)>0$, prove $\exists B\subset A\ \ni0<\lambda(B)<\lambda(A)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue Measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\lambda(A)=\infty$

Claim: $\lambda([a,b]\cap A)>0$ for some $a<b$

Assume on contrary that $\lambda([a,b]\cap A)=0$ for all $a<b$.

Then $[-n,n]\cap A\nearrow A$. This implies
$$
\lambda(A)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lambda( [-n,n]\cap A)=0
$$
It contradicts our assumption $\lambda(A)=\infty$.

Hence, $\lambda([a,b]\cap A)>0$ for some $a<b$.

Take $B=[a,b]\cap A\subset A$, then $0<\lambda(B)<\infty=\lambda(A)$.

Now suppose $0<\lambda(A)<\infty$

There is $x\notin A$, so $A\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\}$.

Now $[x-1/n,x+1/n]^c \cap A\nearrow \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\}\cap A=A$

So, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lambda([x-1/n,x+1/n]^c \cap A)=\lambda(A)>0$. This implies there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lambda([x-1/n,x+1/n]^c \cap A)>0$, and thus $\lambda([x-1/n,x+1/n] \cap A)<\lambda(A)$ as $\lambda([x-1/n,x+1/n]^c \cap A)+\lambda([x-1/n,x+1/n] \cap A)=\lambda(A)$.

I call $B_1=[x-1/n,x+1/n]^c\cap A$ and $B_2=[x-1/n,x+1/n]\cap A$. Then
$0<\lambda(B_1)\le \lambda(A)$ and $0\le \lambda(B_2)<\lambda(A)$.

But I am unable to get a $B\subset A$ such that $0<\lambda(B)<\lambda(A)$.

Can anyone help me find a way out from this? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First suppose $\lambda (A) <\infty$. Let $f(x)=\lambda ((-\infty,x )\cap A)$. Verify that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \lambda [x,y) =y-x$ for $x <y$. Conclude that $f$ is a  continuous fucntion. Now check that $f(x) \to 0$ as $ x \to -\infty$ and $f(x) \to \lambda (A) >0$ as $x \to \infty$. Use IVP of continuous functions.

For the general case observe that there exist $N$ such that $0<\lambda ((-N,N)\cap A) <\infty$ and apply the first case to $(-N,N)\cap A$